# Margin kerning in Xe(La)TeX for TeXlive 2010: how to enable?

Tags: xetex, kerning, microtype

I'm using the pre-release testing version of TeXlive 2010. From what I understand [from the TeXlive Guide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-7800010.2), a new feature is that support for magin kerning has been added to XeTeX.

From what I can tell, it is not enabled by default, though I'm not *certain* about that. (The effect might be subtle enough that I cannot tell.)

Is it possible for me to enable this when compiling a more or less standard XeLaTeX document? If so, how? The **microtype** package still throws an error when I try to use it with xelatex. Will there be an updated version of this package?

Will it be necessary to use certain fonts, or prepare/acquire a special configuration file for each font?

Anyway, I can find very little information about this new feature online. Any light that can be shed would be appreciated.

Comment: Margin kerning can be seen easily. All punctuation (hyphens, commas, ...) at the end of a line are placed a little further to the right, so the right margin of the body of text is formed by the letters, but not by the punctuation.

Comment: One of my favourite uses for the `geometry` package's `showframe` option is to tell for *certain* how much margin kerning is going on. (Load it with the `pass` option if you want to restrict it to just this task.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Geoffrey. This makes it easy to see that there's definitely no margin kerning going on by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install a preliminary version of the `microtype` package.

Comment: Thanks! (I'm marking this as right; it's a bit hard to tell with the site down, but I'm taking your word for it. ;) )

Comment: You can get it here: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423