# Does anything like a "pdfXeLaTeX" exist?

Tags: pdftex, xetex

I have generally been using `pdfLaTeX` to typeset my documents. I recently heard about `XeTeX` which supposedly is the same thing, except has better support for things like unicode and fonts.

Is there a tool which operates as XeTeX does but which allows a direct PDF translation, rather than going through intermediate stages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's called [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org). See also [this question on se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex).

Comment: Can you tell Lualatex that a document uses Unicode as its character encoding, without using inputenc?

Comment: Yes, you should _not_ use inputenc (or anything else) if you're using UTF8 encoded input. For fontencoding, use EU2 fontenc or the fontspec package.

Comment: That was *really* not subtle, Patrick ;-)

Comment: @Charles: LuaTeX expects UTF-8 input, full stop.  Well, that's not the whole story, as Patrick says, but that's how LuaTeX is supposed to ve used.

Answer (score 12):

XeLaTeX outputs a PDF by default. Yes, it does use `xdvipdfmx` along the way, but why should that bother you? No DVI file is left behind.

Comment: One problem is that routing the typesetting through `xdvipdfmx` precludes the use of pdfTeX-like enhancements such as those provided by the `microtype` package.  `microtype` is currently adding support for LuaTeX.

Comment: It's unclear to me that the intermediate level is the problem. Anyway, `microtype` is also adding (partial) support for XeTeX... See my question here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/margin-kerning-in-xelatex-for-texlive-2010-how-to-enable

Comment: `microtype` has added LuaTeX support long ago, and a preliminary version that works with XeTeX is available from http://xetex.tk

Comment: I stand corrected.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @frabjous: The main difference is the different handling of the `graphicx` package on the different platforms (in terms of what image formats are supported..)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't XeLaTeX support every image format that pdfLaTeX does, and then some?

Comment: @frabjous: No idea. My understanding was that embedding things like PNGs and PDFs (the only two formats I care about) was difficult when going through DVI first. I don't have massive amounts of experience in this area though.

Comment: What you say is true for the TeX engine, but XeTeX uses an extended DVI format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX), so I expect them to have added PNG support to that format.