# Changing colors of MATH functions and DRAWING lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, color

My problem is that I want my math functions and drawing illustrations to be in different colors. I want my colors to be defined at the beginning so they will automatically change the color of math and illustration as i like. I was never working with math and drawing before so that's why it is a bit problem for me. 
Thank you very much for your help.

WORKING CODE:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts}



\definecolor{colMATH}{RGB}{255,0,0} % color of the math functions
\definecolor{colILLUS}{RGB}{0,0,255} % line color in illustration

% example
\begin{document}

% MATH
            $$detA=|A|= \left|\begin{array}{cccc}
            a_11 & a_12 & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
            a_21 & a_22 & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
            . & . &  & . \\
            . & . &  & . \\
            . & . &  & . \\
            a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
            \end{array} \right|=\sum{(-1)^ja_{1k_1}\cdot a_{2k_2}\cdot a_{3k_3}\cdot...\cdot a_{nk_n}} $$                                       


% ILLUSTRATION
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(120,100)(-8,0)
   \put(35,5){\vector(1,0){50}}
   \put(88,5){\makebox(0,0){$h$}}
   \put(40,2){\makebox(0,0){$h_A$}}
   \put(70,2){\makebox(0,0){$h_B$}}
   \multiput(40,5)(30,0){2}{\line(0,1){90}}
   \multiput(40,5)(0,10){7}{\line(1,1){30}}
   \multiput(40,35)(6,0){5}{\line(1,0){3}}
   \multiput(40,65)(6,0){5}{\line(1,0){3}}
   \multiput(40,5)(0,30){3}{\circle*{2}}
   \multiput(70,35)(0,15){3}{\circle*{2}}
   \multiput(40,35)(0,30){2}{\line(1,-1){30}}
   \multiput(39.75,15)(.25,0){3}{\line(0,1){10}}
   \multiput(39,15)(0,10){2}{\line(1,0){2}}
   \multiput(69.75,55)(.25,0){3}{\line(0,1){10}}
   \multiput(69.75,40)(.25,0){3}{\line(0,1){5}}
   \multiput(69,35)(0,5){7}{\line(1,0){2}}
   \put(97,60){\makebox(0,0){$
     \left\}\rule[-4mm]{0mm}{8mm}\right.\leftarrow
     \Delta\tau = 2T_{Cs}\mbox{(lokale Uhr)}
     $}}
   \put(98,50){\makebox(0,0){$\leftarrow$ \emph{Explosion der 2. Uhr}}}
   \put(96,42.5){\makebox(0,0){$\left\}\rule[-1.5mm]{0mm}{3mm}\right.
     \hskip1mm\leftarrow\Delta\tau = T_{Cs}\mbox{(lokale Uhr)}$}}
   \put(25,20){\makebox(0,0){$\Delta\tau = T_{Cs}\rightarrow
     \left\{\rule[-4mm]{0mm}{8mm}\right.$}}  %}
   \put(38,8){\makebox(0,0){1}}
   \put(17,35){\makebox(0,0){ \emph{Start der 1. Uhr} $\rightarrow$ 2$A$}}
   \put(13,65){\makebox(0,0)
                {\emph{Explosion der 1. Uhr} $\rightarrow$ 3$A$}}
   \put(93,35){\makebox(0,0)
                { 2$B \leftarrow$ \emph{Start der 2. Uhr}}}
   \put(74,68){\makebox(0,0){$3B$}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO HAVE:
[image]

Comment: This example does not require TikZ, though I would use TikZ instead of a LaTeX picture environment.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, it can be solved using `\everydisplay` for displayed math and the `etoolbox` package for the pictures:

```
\everydisplay{\color{colMATH}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{picture}{\color{colILLUS}}
```

[image: colored environments]

Some advice: your should [not use $$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), further better use math operators such as `\det`, consider using TikZ (or PSTricks), for more math features use `amsmath`. The latter can have problems with `\everydisplay` though.

Comment: This is a partial solution. I've been playing with this as well. The problem is that it doesn't work for ordinary math. You can use `\everymath` to set the color but then the colour of any text after ordinary math in a Tikz `node` will revert to black. (So `\draw node {blah $a=b$ blur};` will colour `blah $a=b$` as requird but will colour `blur` in the default colour.)

Comment: I notice your solution is for the `picture` environment, so I should have rephrased my comment. Still it would be nice to also make it work for TikZ.

Comment: For finer control over the colour of maths, see Will Robertson's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335/86

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it's not for pdflatex.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen True.  It's what switched me to xelatex, as it happens.

Comment: @Andrew I tried switching to XeLaTeX twice and it works nice, but I reverted to `pdflatex` again because it has proper `microtype` support, which XeLaTeX is currently still lacking. (I'd love OpenType support \'a la XeLaTeX in `pdflatex`.)

Comment: Allegedly, it's on its way (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2986/86)

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz THX for the pictures...works perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey pdflatex is my priority here so i can't use that solution on xelatex but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution for *math* but it is not super cool. Is there any other possibility to make it work like this?

**CODE**:

```
\definecolor{colMATH}{RGB}{255,0,0} % color of the math functions


\let\oldbmath\[
\renewcommand{\[}{\begingroup\color{colMATH}\oldbmath}
\let\endoldmath\]
\renewcommand{\]}{\endoldmath\endgroup}


%math function
\[
detA=|A|=
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
       a_11 & a_12   & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
       a_21 & a_22   & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
          . & .      &        & . \\
          . & .      &        & . \\
          . & .      &        & . \\
     a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
\end{array}
\right|=\sum{(-1)^ja_{1k_1}\cdot a_{2k_2}\cdot a_{3k_3}\cdot...\cdot 
a_{nk_n}}
\]
```

Comment: What's bad about Stefan Kottwitz's answer? This one won't work for other display math environments.