# How do I activate hanging punctuation with XeteX under ConTeXt?

Tags: xetex, context, microtype, protrusion

I'm noob at ConTeXt. I want to use auto2 font with ConTeXt, I think the easiest way to do that is using the XeTeX backend. ConTeXt can do some protrusion with pdfTeX and LuaTeX, but with XeTeX it doesn't, but as far as I know [XeTeX does marging kerning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/margin-kerning-in-xelatex-for-texlive-2010-how-to-enable). So why I need to enable it under ConTeXt?

Any clue would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried enabling protrusion using the [method](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Protrusion) for MkII? And ConTeXt MkIV (luatex backend), does support system fonts. So, I will recommend using ConTeXt MkIV.

Comment: I've just tried it, fortunately there wasn't too much differences between the LuaTeX backend and the XeTeX one in my document. Finally it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aditya Make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using luatex (ConTeXt MkIV), you can do the following:

```
%\setupframedtext  [align=hanging]
\definefontfeature [default] [default]
  [
    %protrusion=quality, % partial protrusion
     protrusion=pure,    % full protrusion
  ]

\setupalign [hanging]

\showframe
\starttext
  \input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

For `\framed` and `framedtext` protrusion is *not* enabled by default. You have to set that explicitly (see commented first line). There are several values for the `protrusion` key:

**pure** - full protrusion of only selected punctuation
**punctuation** -   partial protrusion of punctuation and some asymmetrical letters
**alpha**   - variable correction of character widths
**quality**     - combination of punctuation and alpha

See [ConTeXt wiki - Protrusion](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Protrusion)